# Echo certain value from smarty array

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

So currently I have an array with smarty..

```
{foreach from=$_sequences key=k item=v}
  Name => {$v.menu}
  Type => {$v.type}
  Step => {$v.pri} 
  Data =>{$v.data}
{/foreach}
```

which gives me:

> ---
>
> Name => Test
>
> Type => Audio
>
> Step => 1
>
> Data => audio1
>
> ---
>
> Name => Test2
>
> Type => Audio
>
> Step => 2
>
> Data => audio2
>
> ---
>
> Name => Test3
>
> Type => Audio
>
> Step => 3
>
> Data => audio3
>
> ---

Now how would I get the data for step => 2 to echo out?

So from that foreach I only want to display "audio2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this, sorry the modified code

```
{foreach from=$_sequences key=k item=v}
     {if $v.pri == "2"}
                     Name => {$v.menu}  
                     Type => {$v.type}
                     Step => {$v.pri} 
                     Data =>{$v.data}
      {/if}
 {/foreach}
```

Comment: Getting this error

"PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in"

Comment: Oh it's because it is {if $v.pri == "2"} not )

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
{foreach from=$_sequences.1 key=k item=v}
```

where `1` is your second key (I think).
The best way is to assign for `smarty` an associative array - then you will be able to work like:

```
{foreach from=$_sequences.audio2 key=k item=v}
```